# Unexpected 30s delay on suspend

Tags: linux, systemd, suspend

My laptop has an undesirable 30s delay upon every suspend. This has been happening for at least a couple of months now, and I'd finally like to get rid of it, but I do not know what causes it.

Here's the relevant section of /var/log/syslog:

```
Nov 15 12:47:01 exobrain NetworkManager[21274]: <info [1605440821.3196] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Nov 15 12:47:01 exobrain NetworkManager[21274]: <info [1605440821.3198] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 15 12:47:01 exobrain wpa_supplicant[555]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Nov 15 12:47:01 exobrain NetworkManager[21274]: <info [1605440821.3321] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 15 12:47:01 exobrain NetworkManager[21274]: <info [1605440821.3324] device (72:1F:BB:15:3C:B3): state change: disconnected -unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 15 12:47:01 exobrain NetworkManager[21274]: <info [1605440821.3328] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Nov 15 12:47:01 exobrain wpa_supplicant[555]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Nov 15 12:47:31 exobrain systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Nov 15 12:47:31 exobrain systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Nov 15 12:47:34 exobrain systemd-sleep[72905]: Suspending system...
Nov 15 12:47:34 exobrain kernel: [41584.276223] PM: suspend entry (deep)
```

As you can see, the 30s delay occurs between NetworkManager being asleep and systemd actually going into suspend.

What causes this delay and how can I eliminate it?

Here's some system info:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:        Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
# uname -r
5.4.0-52-generic
```

Some additional info:

- The delay does *not* occur with pm-suspend.
- The configuration files /etc/systemd/sleep.conf and /etc/systemd/logind.conf are both empty, containing only the default values in commented out form.
- `systemd-analyze blame` shows only one item taking substantially longer than a second, namely NetworkManager-wait-online.service with 7.4s.

Comment: I have the same issue for some times now. It  seems there is a process ongoing and systemd wait 30s before killing it.

Comment: @ppr: are you referring to an actual process in the operating system? Which process is that? BTW I've implemented a workaround by creating a hotkey that runs pm-suspend, which does not depend on systemd. That works well so far, although of course it doesn't address the underlying issue.

Comment: No I was not referring to an actual process ongoing. But it seems to me systemd fails to stop a service, and then wait 30s before killing it to put the computer to sleep. I also read that this 30s delay could be a intended feature (even if I have some trouble to believe that).

Comment: Do you use a docking station?

Comment: @ppr: No, I don't use a docking station. Do you? If you happen to know which service systemd fails to stop, that could be some useful input.

Answer (score 1):

Bug in Xubuntu 20.04 with same symptoms due to a screensaver mismatch. You might check your settings for that on Ubuntu as well.The process it's waiting for might just be for the screensaver to exit (even if it's not actually doing anything.) Unfortunately on Xubuntu if you disable the screensaver, the problem still occurs!
I've replaced the X-screensaver with the one from Mate, which doesn't cause a problem. Also I've emptied the values on the X-screensaver and the power manager (whether or not running.) Seems to fix it. I then set the system to suspend after 26 minutes activity. This seems to work without causing the other problem.

Comment: Thank you! Glad that it works for you now. However I don't even have xscreensaver installed, so it can hardly be a screensaver issue, right? Could you elaborate a bit on what you mean by "empty the values on the power manager"? Which values are those?

Answer (score 1):

On my system, there is a file, `/usr/lib/systemd/logind.conf.d/unattended-upgrades-logind-maxdelay.conf`:

```
[Login]
# delay
InhibitDelayMaxSec=30
```

Changing `InhibitDelayMaxSec` to `1` helped to suspend immediately.

Comment: Perhaps you could add the name of the file? I'm on a different computer now and this problem no longer afflicts me, but it may still be helpful to others.

Comment: @Saibot, sure, I've added it originally, but messed up with code formatting, so it became hidden O_o